# Display variable on-screen using Android by TextViews

Tags: android, xml, variables, textview

I'm having a slight problem trying to display a variable on-screen.

Right now I have a tabbed layout. In the fourth tab there is a nested `ActivityGroup` which has a mapactivity inside of it.

The trouble is this map activities `setContentView` is set to `R.layout.gps`

I am trying to display the distance traveled on-screen ontop or beside the map to show how far the user has travelled.

I can get text to display on-screen by creating a text view inside of the XML. However using this method I am unable to link it to a `Double` variable inside of the activity.

At the same time if I create a `TextView t = new TextView(this)` it will not be displayed on-screen as the set content is now on it.

If anyone could shed any light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the TextView you want to use in res/layout/gps.xml has the following in it:

`android:id="@+id/mytextview"`

And then get use Klaus's code to find your TextView in your Java code:

`TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);`
`myTextView.setText("My double value is " + doubleValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a TextView in your XML with the id of mytextview.

Use:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
```

to get a dynamic reference to the TextView. Then you can use

```
myTextView.setText("My double value is " + doubleValue);
```

to update it as you go along.

Comment: I tried to do that as well but I got this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carbonaware.gps/com.carbonaware.gps.FirstGroup}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carbonaware.gps/com.carbonaware.gps.gps}: java.lang.NullPointerExcep....... but it will work if I don't use the method .setText which has me confused